# Find subset in List of objects based on matched property in string array

Tags: c#, linq

I have a scenario where I have a comma separated string of admin ids received as controller method parameter.
I am splitting it and storing it to a string array

```
string[] strSelectedAdmin = selectedEnrollAdmin.Split(',');
```

I have a list of Admin DataContract `List<Admins>` each item has 3 properties -

1. ID(nothing but each id present in above string array)
2. AdminName
3. AdminType

I get all possible AdminList from a service method

```
List<Admins> allAdminList = someserviceclient.Admins;
```

I want to filter out a subset list from `allAdminList` based on matching adminIds in the string array `strSelectedAdmin`

Can you help me with the best way here. May be a combination of foreach and linq queriesif possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @Steffsww's answer, you could do it all in one line.  I provided two options since OP is using a string id field, but most cases an int id field is probably the situation this would resolve:

If your object has a string Id property:

```
var admins = allAdminList.Where(admin=>selectedEnrollAdmin.Split(',').Contains(admin.Id));
```

If your object has an integer Id property:

```
var admins = allAdminList.Where(admin=>selectedEnrollAdmin.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList().Contains(admin.Id));
```

Regarding the below comment about a null `selectedEnrollAdmin` value, I see a few options:

1: Make the parameter have a default and the above code should work no problem:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string selectedEnrollAdmin = "")
```

2: escape before you get to your logic:

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedEnrollAdmin)) return; //throw new Exception('some message');
```

3: Handle it inline:

```
var admins = allAdminList.Where(admin=>(selectedEnrollAdmin??string.Empty).Split(',')...);
```

Comment: thank you both. @JasonWilczak - if the selectedEnrollAdmin is null, this code will fail isnt it? is there a way to handle null without explicitly checking it?

Comment: THanks, allthough ID is a string field, not int for some reason in the existing code,

Comment: Interesting, yeah I added the Int32 parsing option since in most cases, i think, an id field would be an int.

Answer (score 1):

firstly I would find the IDs that are common to both lists. 
Then using these results I would find the Admins.

So you could try:

```
var results = strSelectedAdmin.Intersect(allAdminList.Select(admin => admin.Id));
var Admins = allAdminList.Where(admin => results.Contains(admin.Id));
```